# When can we apply phasor analysis to an \$RLC\$ circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, sine, phasor, steady-state, sinusoidal

[This answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/697694/334551) of mine shows that not every \$RLC\$ circuit reaches sinusoidal steady state at input frequency.

A well-known theorem states that:

> **If all natural frequencies of a uniquely solvable LTI circuit have negative real parts, then the circuit reaches a unique sinusoidal steady state at input frequency.**

Is there any way to strengthen the condition of this theorem to be able to immediately, without computing the natural frequencies for each given circuit, determine a general class of \$RLC\$ circuits that reach sinusoidal steady state and thus can be analyzed using phasors?

I'm want a proof or a reference to a proof if one provides an answer.

I suspect the condition could have something to do with having at least one resistor and not having some resonance-prone \$LC\$ connections. But that's just a guess. I don't know how to show this or even how to properly formulate the correct condition.

Answer (score 1):

> *Is there any way to strengthen the condition of this theorem to be
> able to immediately, without computing the natural frequencies for
> each given circuit, determine a general class of RLC circuits that
> reach sinusoidal steady state*

I would compute the Q-factor of the circuit. If the Q-factor is not \$\infty\$ (infinity) then it has a finite value and therefore will reach a steady state. Q-factor depends on the values of R, L and C and we don't need to compute anything else. When the Q-factor is \$\infty\$ its poles have no negative real value.

Comment: I want to determine if the circuit reaches sinusoidal steady state at input frequency. Finite Q-factor could only indicate BIBO stability

Comment: As far as I know that condition does indicate AC sinusoidal stability.

Comment: Wow, interesting. Can you provide a proof/reference to a proof?

Comment: I can't provide a proof (and, I note that your question didn't ask for one).

Comment: \$Q^{-1}\$ is proportional to the energy dissipated per oscillation period. If \$Q\$ is finite, the oscillation at the resonant frequency will continuously lose energy and eventually die down.

Comment: @Andyaka I did ask for a proof in the question

Comment: @Puk how can I be sure resonant frequency is the only thing that could possibly cause an arbitrary \$RLC\$ circuit with sine input to not have sine output of the input frequency? And how do I generally exclude the possibility of circuit containing a structure that results in traisient side frequency that dies away with time?

Comment: @Sgg8 I parsed the question and the only text that was a question was what I embedded in my answer. Having said that I noticed what you said about what you'd like to have. In the process of thinking about this I focussed on Q-factor and realized that an infinite Q factor is the only implicit condition that doesn't allow the sinewave ever to settle down. Hence Q-factor requires no further proof other than you reading up on the strict definition realting energy input and output.

Comment: @Andyaka 1) "and realized that an infinite Q factor is the only implicit condition that doesn't allow the sinewave ever to settle down" - why? 2) Having thought about this more thoroughly, I never saw a definition for a Q-factor that wouldn't involve "energy per period" part. In general, responce of an \$RLC\$ circuit often has an exponential term, not only the sine one, thus is not periodic, so this doesn't seem applicable to my question so far

Comment: @Puk same as 2) above goes for your argument. I'm asking about a general \$RLC\$ circuit, so the responce doesn't have to be periodic